# Navbar scroll down disappear, scroll up reappear w/ slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm looking to make a navigation bar like devmounta.in. I have a basic one working but it doesn't have the nice sliding animation that DevMountain's has. I'm looking to add the nice sliding animation to my site.

HTML:

```
    <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Logo -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainNavBar">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">RoadAware</a>
            </div>
            <!-- Menu Items -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainNavBar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>      
</header>
```

JS:

```
$(window).scroll(
{
    previousTop: 0
}, 
function () {
var currentTop = $(window).scrollTop();
if (currentTop < this.previousTop) {
    $("header").show();
} else {
    $("header").hide();
}
this.previousTop = currentTop;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The site you referenced uses a plugin called [Headroom.js](http://wicky.nillia.ms/headroom.js/). See working example.

```js
//HeadroomJS
var myElement = document.querySelector("header");
var headroom = new Headroom(myElement);
headroom.init();
```

```css
body,
html {
  margin-top: 65px;
}
header .container {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 5px
}
.headroom {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none
}
.headroom--pinned {
  top: 0
}
.headroom--unpinned {
  top: -40%
}
.notfound {
  font-family: proxima-nova;
  padding-top: 100px;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)
}
.notfound h1 {
  margin-top: 8%;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #fff
}
.notfound h5 {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: #fff
}
.notfound span {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 700%;
  color: #00aeef;
  font-weight: 700;
  outline: #fff 1px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/headroom/0.7.0/headroom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body>
  <header class="headroom">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Logo -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainNavBar"> <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>

          </button> <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">RoadAware</a>

        </div>
        <!-- Menu Items -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainNavBar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a>

            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <div class="container">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer
    took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset
    sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
    standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
    It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the
    printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries,
    but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
    including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled
    it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
    and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since
    the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in
    the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
    industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic
    typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem
    Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
    It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer
    took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset
    sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
    standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
    It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.slideUp()` instead of `.hide()` and `.slideDown()` instead of `.show()`

```
$(window).scroll({
    previousTop: 0
},

function () {
    var currentTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (currentTop < this.previousTop) {
        $("header").slideUp();
    } else {
        $("header").slideDown();
    }
    this.previousTop = currentTop;
});
```

Comment: Yes but it creates a weird lag, it there a way to speed up the slide?

Comment: Just pass the speed parameter to the slideUp and slideDown functions